# Dataframe.applymap worked fine - Column disappeared

Tags: python

Here is the following test dataframe

```
In [32]: frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3)*1000000, columns=list('bde'), index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])

In [33]: frame
Out[33]: 
                   b              d             e
Utah    1.582808e+05 -351731.845560 -5.832029e+04
Ohio   -1.653296e+06 -336185.349586 -1.170889e+05
Texas  -4.741239e+04 -964691.055175 -9.489544e+05
Oregon -1.103707e+06  523821.598282 -1.245662e+06
```

I want to change column b and d so that the elements are integers, but not column e.

```
In [35]: frame[['b','d']].applymap(int)
Out[35]: 
              b       d
Utah     158280 -351731
Ohio   -1653296 -336185
Texas    -47412 -964691
Oregon -1103707  523821
```

That frame change but the column disappeared. How do I get it back the last column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply

```
In [36]: frame[['b','d']] = frame[['b','d']].applymap(int)

In [37]: frame
Out[37]: 
              b       d             e
Utah     158280 -351731 -5.832029e+04
Ohio   -1653296 -336185 -1.170889e+05
Texas    -47412 -964691 -9.489544e+05
Oregon -1103707  523821 -1.245662e+06
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `assign`:

```
frame.assign(b = frame.b.astype(int), d = frame.d.astype(int))
```

Output:

```
             b       d             e
Utah    524658 -965098  2.762532e+04
Ohio   -980245 -629015  1.042148e+06
Texas  -180861  -60601 -5.128917e+05
Oregon -752839  469190 -5.036541e+05
```